# Can the 'startsWith' function in GitHub Actions handle a list of strings?

Tags: github, github-actions

I am trying to write a job that would lint *only* the changed files, on a push or pull request.
I succeeded in writing a job that retrieves the changed files but when I am passing the list of files to the lint step, it is being skipped.
I on purpose changing a bunch of files.
The code looks like this:

```
name: Lint Changed Files

on: [push, pull_request]

jobs:
  changed_files:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
      - name: Checkout code
        uses: actions/checkout@v2
        with:
          fetch-depth: 0

      - name: Get list of added and modified files
        id: changed-files
        uses: tj-actions/changed-files@v39

      - name: Echo changed files
        run: |
          echo "Changed Files: ${{ steps.changed-files.outputs.all_changed_files }}" 

  lint:
    needs: [changed_files]
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
    - name: Lint Python scripts
      if: endsWith(needs.changed_files.outputs.all_changed_files, '.py')
      run: |
        pip install flake8
        echo "${{ needs.changed_files.outputs.all_changed_files }}" | tr ' ' '\n' | grep \\.py$ | xargs flake8

    - name: Lint shell scripts
      if: endsWith(needs.changed_files.outputs.all_changed_files, '.sh')
      run: |
        sudo apt-get install shellcheck
        echo "${{ needs.changed_files.outputs.all_changed_files }}" | tr ' ' '\n' | grep \\.sh$ | xargs shellcheck

    - name: Lint YAML files
      if: endsWith(needs.changed_files.outputs.all_changed_files, 'yaml')
      run: |
        pip install yamllint
        echo "${{ needs.changed_files.outputs.all_changed_files }}" | tr ' ' '\n' | grep \\.y[a]?ml$ | xargs yamllint
```

Can the 'startsWith' handle a list of strings (in this case, filenames)?
And if not, what is the best way of doing so?
Thank you!

Comment: See https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/expressions#startswith

Comment: I already saw it.
there is nothing there about a list, only a single string.
I guess that it is a no

Answer (score 1):

The [`startsWith` function](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/expressions#startswith) in GitHub Actions does *not* handle a list of strings.
It is designed to check if a single string starts with another specified string.

You are using the `endsWith` function, but it operates under a similar principle as `startsWith`, checking if a single string ends with a specified substring.

The current approach of using `endsWith` to check if any of the changed files end with a specific extension (e.g., `.py`, `.sh`, `yaml`) will not work as intended since `needs.changed_files.outputs.all_changed_files` is a single string containing a space-separated list of all changed files, and `endsWith` will only check the end of this entire string.

---

A better approach would be to use a shell command to process the list of changed files and determine if any of the files have the desired extension:

```yaml
name: Lint Changed Files

on: [push, pull_request]

jobs:
  changed_files:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
      - name: Checkout code
        uses: actions/checkout@v2
        with:
          fetch-depth: 0

      - name: Get list of added and modified files
        id: changed-files
        uses: tj-actions/changed-files@v39

      - name: Echo changed files
        run: |
          echo "Changed Files: ${{ steps.changed-files.outputs.all_changed_files }}" 

  lint:
    needs: [changed_files]
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
    - name: Check for Python files
      id: check-python
      run: |
        echo "::set-output name=python::$(echo "${{ needs.changed_files.outputs.all_changed_files }}" | grep -q \\.py && echo true || echo false)"
    
    - name: Lint Python scripts
      if: steps.check-python.outputs.python == 'true'
      run: |
        pip install flake8
        echo "${{ needs.changed_files.outputs.all_changed_files }}" | tr ' ' '\n' | grep \\.py$ | xargs flake8

    - name: Check for Shell files
      id: check-shell
      run: |
        echo "::set-output name=shell::$(echo "${{ needs.changed_files.outputs.all_changed_files }}" | grep -q \\.sh && echo true || echo false)"
    
    - name: Lint shell scripts
      if: steps.check-shell.outputs.shell == 'true'
      run: |
        sudo apt-get install shellcheck
        echo "${{ needs.changed_files.outputs.all_changed_files }}" | tr ' ' '\n' | grep \\.sh$ | xargs shellcheck
    
    - name: Check for YAML files
      id: check-yaml
      run: |
        echo "::set-output name=yaml::$(echo "${{ needs.changed_files.outputs.all_changed_files }}" | grep -q \\.y[a]?ml && echo true || echo false)"

    - name: Lint YAML files
      if: steps.check-yaml.outputs.yaml == 'true'
      run: |
        pip install yamllint
        echo "${{ needs.changed_files.outputs.all_changed_files }}" | tr ' ' '\n' | grep \\.y[a]?ml$ | xargs yamllint
```

You would now have separate steps added, to check for the presence of files with each of the desired extensions.
These steps use the `grep` command to search for the extensions in the list of changed files, and set an output variable to `true` if any files with the extension are found.
The `if` conditions for the linting steps have been updated to check these output variables, so the linting steps will only run if there are files with the corresponding extensions among the changed files.

Answer (score 1):

You do not need to fetch the complete changed files' list and then filter it yourself, [tj-actions/changed-files](https://github.com/tj-actions/changed-files) already provides a [`files`](https://github.com/tj-actions/changed-files?tab=readme-ov-file#input_files) input parameter that you can use for this filtering.

Example:

```yaml
name: changed_files_test

on: workflow_dispatch

jobs:
  changed-files:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    outputs:
      py: ${{ steps.changed-files-py.outputs.all_changed_files }}
      sh: ${{ steps.changed-files-sh.outputs.all_changed_files }}
      yaml: ${{ steps.changed-files-yaml.outputs.all_changed_files }}

    steps:
      - name: Checkout
        uses: actions/checkout@v4
        with:
          fetch-depth: 0

      - name: Changed files (py)
        id: changed-files-py
        uses: tj-actions/changed-files@v39
        with:
          files: '**.py'

      - name: Changed files (sh)
        id: changed-files-sh
        uses: tj-actions/changed-files@v39
        with:
          files: '**.sh'

      - name: Changed files (yaml/yml)
        id: changed-files-yaml
        uses: tj-actions/changed-files@v39
        with:
          files: |
            **.yml
            **.yaml

  lint:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    needs: [changed-files]

    steps:
      - name: Lint (py)
        if: ${{ needs.changed-files.outputs.py }}
        run: flake8 ${{ needs.changed-files.outputs.py }}

      - name: Lint (sh)
        if: ${{ needs.changed-files.outputs.sh }}
        run: shellcheck ${{ needs.changed-files.outputs.sh }}

      - name: Lint (yaml)
        if: ${{ needs.changed-files.outputs.yaml }}
        run: yamllint ${{ needs.changed-files.outputs.yaml }}
```

Answer (score 0):

A simplified approach you could take is

```yaml
name: Lint Changed Files

on: [push, pull_request]

jobs:
  changed_files:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
      - name: Checkout code
        uses: actions/checkout@v4
        with:
          fetch-depth: 0

      - name: Get list of added and modified files
        id: changed-files
        uses: tj-actions/changed-files@v40
        with:
          files_yaml: |
            python_files:
              - '**.py'
            shell_scripts:
              - '**.sh'
            yaml_files:
              - '**.yaml'              

      - name: List changed python file(s).
        if: steps.changed-files.outputs.python_files_any_changed == 'true'
        run: |
          echo "Changed python files: ${{ steps.changed-files.outputs.python_files_all_changed_files }}"

      - name: List changed shell script(s).
        if: steps.changed-files.outputs.shell_scripts_any_changed == 'true'
        run: |
          echo "Changed shell scripts: ${{ steps.changed-files.outputs.shell_scripts_all_changed_files }}"

      - name: List changed yaml file(s).
        if: steps.changed-files.outputs.yaml_files_any_changed == 'true'
        run: |
          echo "Changed python files: ${{ steps.changed-files.outputs.yaml_files_all_changed_files }}"
```

You can pass the list to any linter directly without any complex logic

E.g

```yaml
..

      - name: Lint changed python file(s).
        if: steps.changed-files.outputs.python_files_any_changed == 'true'
        run: |
          flake8 ${{ steps.changed-files.outputs.python_files_all_changed_files }}"

..
```